# Does ng-bootstrap support specifically Angular 2?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Does **ng-bootstrap** supports specifically **Angular 2**?

Comment: What do you mean by specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)?

**Angular (requires Angular version 5 or higher, tested with 5.0.2)**

You could easily google that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only support for Angular 2.0.0, and not Angular 4+, you can use the version *1.0.0-alpha.18* of ng-bootstrap, but you will loose many features and fix.